# Convert Last Num To String

Tags: c#, string, numbers, c#-2.0

I'm getting the last number of a number , but have to convert last number to a string, as `14 ="Four" , 12 ="two"`

```
using System;

namespace Program
{

    class LastDigit
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please write your number:");
            long n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            long lastDigit = n % (10);  //or int or double - whatever numeral data type suits you

            string word = "";

        }
    }
}
```

Except : 10 = "zero" , 14 = "Four"

Comment: Are you really confined to C# 2.0?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - chances are lower than 0 % :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an array of alphabetic numbers and call the appropriate index.

```
const string[] alphabaticNumbers=new string[]{"Zero","One" ,....};
string word= alphabaticNumbers[lastDigit];
```